# How to get html source of page, after all it scripts was called?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'am trying to parse site. The site (i suppose) using scripts and data bases to load data from (dynamically?). And this is my problem... I am trying to grab data through C# (unfortunately i don't have access to code right now) or JS. And it seems like either C# and JS, get only template of the site, but don't wait until all scripts executed. So this is my question, is there any way to get ALL html source? Maybe call scripts somehow. Or make a request, wait for 10 seconds, and then write source html data into variable?

Here is my JS code.

```
function request(link)
{

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', link, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() . 
        {console.log(xhr.readyState);};

    xhr.send();

    let data  = xhr.responseText;

    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = data.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, 
        '');

    return tempDiv;
}

function loadFile(url, timeout, callback) 
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 3);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("The request for " + url + " timed out.");
        };
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                callback.apply(xhr, args);
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.timeout = timeout;
    xhr.send(null);

    let data  = xhr.responseText;
    return data;
}

function showMessage (message) {
    console.log(message + this.responseText);
}

function include(scriptUrl)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", scriptUrl);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ((xmlhttp.status == 200) && (xmlhttp.readyState == 4))
       {
            eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
       }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();

    let data  = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = data.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, 
     '');

    return tempDiv;
}
```

All this functions do not work as i want.

Comment: I don't have any specific product recommendations, but the term for what you're looking for is often called a "headless browser".  Currently you're manually making the HTTP requests and getting the responses, without any actual browser functionality.  A headless browser is an in-code component which will make the page request and then mimic all of the functionality of a browser, making subsequent requests and executing JavaScript and updating the DOM state accordingly.

Comment: Probably you could use a WebClient in C# and wait until it's fully loaded. (`await _semaphoreslim.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds("10"));`)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really practical - you're trying to load an HTML page, all associated scripts, then run them on the HTML page as if they were in a proper browser environment, but within your current browser session.

This sort of thing is feasible with the `jsdom` library if you were running on the server-side (NodeJS), because it simulates browser behaviour: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom. So you could do

```
JSDOM.fromURL("https://example.com/", { runScripts: "dangerously" }).then(dom => {
   console.log(dom.serialize()); //turn the page back into HTML
});
```

...to get the whole thing.

Comment: I am new js user, and i do not understand how to include JSDOM. Like, i downloaded it and installed into VS Code, i have node_modules folder in my project, but still have the Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: JSDOM is not defined".

Comment: If you're running in a NodeJS environment, you should just be able to do `const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');` before you use it. I linked to the documentation (in fact I pretty much copied my code from there), so have a look at that if you get stuck

Comment: Now i have this "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined";

Comment: Like I said in my answer, this code won't work in a browser (like Chrome). It needs to be run in a NodeJs server environment. Does that make sense?